# confused with def main() and def menu() order

Tags: python, function, loops, menu, program-entry-point

After I pick an option my program is supposed to give me the area of a rectangle, circle, or triangle after I input the unit of whatever shape. But instead of stopping after one area formula, it continues to do all of them. How do I stop this?

```
import math

def main():
    menu()
    if choice ==1:
        circle()
    if choice == 2:
        rectangle()
    if choice ==3:
        triangle()


def menu():
    global choice
    choice = int(input('choose option 1-3:'))

    while choice < 1 or choice > 3:
        print('error. must choose option 1-3')
        choice = int(input('try again:'))




circle()

rectangle()

triangle()

def circle ():
    radCir = float(input('enter radius of circle:'))
    areaCir = math.pi*radCir**2

    print('area of circle:',format(areaCir,'.2f'))

def rectangle():
    global choice
    length = float(input('enter length of rectangle:'))
    width = float(input('enter width of rectangle:'))

    areaRec = length * width

    print('area of rectangle:',format(areaRec, '.2f'))

def triangle():
    base = float(input('enter base of triangle:'))
    height = float(input('enter height of triangle:'))

    areaTri = base * height * .5

    print('area of triangle:',format(areaTri,'.2f'))


main()
```

Comment: `circle()`,  `rectangle()` and `triangle()` are module-level function calls that have absolutely nothing to do with the flow of your code that you're trying to control inside the functions (in other words, they'll be called regardless of what you do in your `main` or `menu` function). You should call _one_ of those functions based on the input, which you've already implemented in `main()`

Comment: This code does not produce the error you describe; it produces a `NameError`, because you're trying to call `circle` before it's defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you are calling functions before you define them. Remove the calls to the functions before the definitions i.e. delete:

```
circle()

rectangle()

triangle()
```

that occur right above `def circle ():...`.